# Epslatex stand alone does not add \end{document}

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot, eps, gnuplot-iostream

I'm trying to use epslatex to create a standalone but the file .tex created can't be compiled because  \end{document} and \end{picture} are missing, why is this ?
Sample code

```
    set terminal epslatex standalone
    set output "sample.tex" 
    plot "data.txt" using 1:2  pointtype 1 pointsize 1
```

I'm plotting data from a text file maybe is this the problem ?
Anyway the figure is created only the .tex file is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
unset output
```

to the end to get a complete TeX file. Otherwise, the file is not written completely to disk.

The terminal `pdfcairo` allows to have several plot commands, each resulting in an own page in the pdf file. I first thought epslatex may do something similar, but it doesn't